# How to change the colour of the grey strips in XYPlot in wxFreeCharts

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have been trying to make white strips around the plot but i was not able to figure out how this can be done.

I checked the wxFreeChart documentation but didn't find anything related to my question. If someone have tried this before please help

here is the link of wxFreeChart: http://wxcode.sourceforge.net/docs/freechart/classXYPlot.html